# SP 2013 approval workflow - collect comments from approvers

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval-process

I have the following case:

- I need to establish an approval workflow with the option to leave comments by the approvers.
- No workflow templates are available on my server and I cannot administer it - I am just a user
- My environment: SP 2013, SP Designer 2013

What I did:

- I created a list with a 2013 workflow started automatically when a new item is created.
- Workflow looks like that:

[image: Workflow]

- When a task is created I want to use the description field to enable the approver to leave comments.
- After the task is approved I want to move the description field value to a specific field in the custom list. To do it I added the following step to the workflow:
  [image]

Now, the problem starts exactly here. The workflow is suspended due to conversion error -  string cannot be converted to integer. I checked it and the variable taskID stores an ID which looks like: 030c8d4f-6e24-4567-8833-584728c61b95 - I am quite new to SP but it looks like a global, unique ID and in this form cannot be converted to integer.

On the other hand when I go to the task list the id (from column ID) of the newly created task is something like 25, which misses completely the task id recorded in the workflow when the task is created.

So, how can I match the newly created task with the list item and ultimately collect the comments? Maybe my approach is compeletely wrong and a different approach is needed? Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TaskID variable is a Guid - a 36 character string (32 without the hyphens).

The proper way to find the Task would be use the TaskID as a string linked to the field GUID